# Deep sort XML with XSLT?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

Can I sort XML content recursively that is parent node are sorting by sorted content of its children ? 
For example. I have XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<catalog xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title dt:dt="string" as="ddd">Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <artist>Alan Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1998</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

And such sorting XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:ext="urn:extension-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl ext">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>

      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction() | comment()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result is:

```
<catalog xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <cd>
    <artist>Alan Dylan</artist>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <country>USA</country>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <title as="ddd" dt:dt="string">Empire Burlesque</title>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <country>EU</country>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <country>USA</country>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <country>UK</country>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <country>UK</country>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <year>1998</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <country>UK</country>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

But correct answer should be:

```
<catalog xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <cd>
    <artist>Alan Dylan</artist>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <country>USA</country>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <title as="ddd" dt:dt="string">Empire Burlesque</title>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <country>UK</country>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <year>1998</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <country>UK</country>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <country>USA</country>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <country>EU</country>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <country>UK</country>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Because CDs with artists "Bee Gees" and "Bonnie Tyler" are above then "Eros Ramazzotti" and "Dolly Parton" in sort order. So, true sort rule should be:

- Sort all children of cd nodes by node local-name + content
- Sort all cd nodes by sorted content of its children.

Is it possible? 
XSLT - 1.0

Comment: I propose self answer based on Chad Nouis method. Look bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose self answer based on Chad Nouis method.
Deep sorting XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:ext="urn:extension-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl ext">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- XSLT identity transformation -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:variable name="xorder">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="sort-children"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($xorder)/*">
        <xsl:sort select="child::*[position() = 1]"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="sort-children">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>

      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:sort select="text()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction() | comment()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is same as in the Chad Nouis answer, but attributes are sorted too. This XSLT can sort more deeper then one level. For example. XML with two level of recursion (catalog/list/cd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<catalog xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <list>
    <cd>
      <title>Hide your heart</title>
      <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
      <country>UK</country>
      <company>CBS Records</company>
      <price>9.90</price>
      <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <title>Greatest Hits</title>
      <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
      <country>USA</country>
      <company>RCA</company>
      <price>9.90</price>
      <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <title>Still got the blues</title>
      <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
      <country>UK</country>
      <company>Virgin records</company>
      <price>10.20</price>
      <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
  </list>
  <list>
    <cd>
      <title>Eros</title>
      <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
      <country>EU</country>
      <company>BMG</company>
      <price>9.90</price>
      <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <title dt:dt="string" as="ddd">Empire Burlesque</title>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      <artist>Alan Dylan</artist>
      <country>USA</country>
      <company>Columbia</company>
      <price>10.90</price>
      <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
  </list>
  <list>
    <cd>
      <title>One night only</title>
      <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
      <country>UK</country>
      <company>Polydor</company>
      <price>10.90</price>
      <year>1998</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <title>One night only</title>
      <artist>Aa</artist>
      <country>UK</country>
      <company>Polydor</company>
      <price>100</price>
      <year>2013</year>
    </cd>
  </list>
</catalog>
```

Will be transformed to XML:

```
<catalog xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <list>
    <cd>
      <artist>Alan Dylan</artist>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
      <company>Columbia</company>
      <country>USA</country>
      <price>10.90</price>
      <title as="ddd" dt:dt="string">Empire Burlesque</title>
      <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
      <company>BMG</company>
      <country>EU</country>
      <price>9.90</price>
      <title>Eros</title>
      <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
  </list>
  <list>
    <cd>
      <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
      <company>CBS Records</company>
      <country>UK</country>
      <price>9.90</price>
      <title>Hide your heart</title>
      <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
      <company>RCA</company>
      <country>USA</country>
      <price>9.90</price>
      <title>Greatest Hits</title>
      <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
      <company>Virgin records</company>
      <country>UK</country>
      <price>10.20</price>
      <title>Still got the blues</title>
      <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
  </list>
  <list>
    <cd>
      <artist>Aa</artist>
      <company>Polydor</company>
      <country>UK</country>
      <price>100</price>
      <title>One night only</title>
      <year>2013</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
      <company>Polydor</company>
      <country>UK</country>
      <price>10.90</price>
      <title>One night only</title>
      <year>1998</year>
    </cd>
  </list>
</catalog>
```

As can you see, every list/cd group is sorted by its artist's nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The following XSLT 1.0 example uses the `node-set()` function from the MSXML library. It uses template modes so nodes can be processed multiple times.

For each `<cd>` in the original XML, the XSLT sorts the child `<artist>` elements, outputs the sorted `<artist>` elements, then sorts the remaining child elements by element name, and then outputs those sorted elements.

The code hard-codes usage of the `<artist>` elements. I believe this isn't as generic of a solution as you requested, but the code should be adaptable to a more generic version pretty easily.

### XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- XSLT identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <xsl:variable name="x">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="sort-cd-children"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($x)/cd">
                <xsl:sort select="artist[position() = 1]"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd" mode="sort-cd-children">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="artist">
                <xsl:sort select="text()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::artist)]">
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### XML Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    <cd>
        <artist>Alan Dylan</artist>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <country>USA</country>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <title dt:dt="string" as="ddd">Empire Burlesque</title>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <country>UK</country>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <title>One night only</title>
        <year>1998</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <country>UK</country>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <country>USA</country>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <country>EU</country>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <title>Eros</title>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <country>UK</country>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a good base for more general XSLT. I'll try to use it.

Comment: Chad, can you test my XSLT proposed in my answer ?

Comment: @23W, your XSLT works great. It's clean and appropriately generic.